# Get Previous Record by Group SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following table:

```
ID  GROUPID     ODATE       OTIME       OVALUE
1   A           2014-05-31  00:00:00    1207432.6
2   A           2014-05-31  01:00:00    1209064     
3   A           2014-05-31  02:00:00    1210698     
4   A           2014-05-31  03:00:00    1212333.3   
5   A           2014-05-31  04:00:00    1213967.7   
6   B           2014-05-31  00:00:00    2110016     
7   B           2014-05-31  01:00:00    2110016     
8   B           2014-05-31  02:00:00    2110016     
9   B           2014-05-31  03:00:00    2110016     
10  B           2014-05-31  04:00:00    2110016     
11  C           2014-05-31  00:00:00    2326592.6   
12  C           2014-05-31  01:00:00    2328088.8
13  C           2014-05-31  02:00:00    2329590.3   
14  C           2014-05-31  03:00:00    2331094.5   
15  C           2014-05-31  04:00:00    2332598
```

Then I run this syntax:

```
SELECT 
A.ID, A.GroupID, A.oDate, A.oTime, 
A.oValue, MAX(B.oValue) AS Prev_oValue, A.oValue - MAX(B.oValue) AS oResult
FROM
Table1 AS A LEFT OUTER JOIN Table1 AS B ON B.GroupID = A.GroupID AND B.oValue < A.oValue
GROUP BY
A.ID, A.GroupID, A.oDate, A.oTime, A.oValue
ORDER BY A.GroupID, A.oDate, A.oTime
```

I want to have the following result:

```
ID  GROUPID     ODATE       OTIME       OVALUE      PREV_OVALUE     ORESULT
1   A           2014-05-31  00:00:00    1207432.6   (null)          (null)
2   A           2014-05-31  01:00:00    1209064     1207432.6       1631.4
3   A           2014-05-31  02:00:00    1210698     1209064         1634
4   A           2014-05-31  03:00:00    1212333.3   1210698         1635.3
5   A           2014-05-31  04:00:00    1213967.7   1212333.3        1634.4
6   B           2014-05-31  00:00:00    2110016     (null)          (null)
7   B           2014-05-31  01:00:00    2110016     2110016         0
8   B           2014-05-31  02:00:00    2110016     2110016         0
9   B           2014-05-31  03:00:00    2110016     2110016         0
10  B           2014-05-31  04:00:00    2110016     2110016         0
11  C           2014-05-31  00:00:00    2326592.6   (null)          (null)
12  C           2014-05-31  01:00:00    2328088.8   2326592.6       1496.2
13  C           2014-05-31  02:00:00    2329590.3   2328088.8       1501.5
14  C           2014-05-31  03:00:00    2331094.5   2329590.3       1504.2
15  C           2014-05-31  04:00:00    2332598     2331094.5       1503.5
```

Check on [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eadf8/1)

What I want is, get the previous value based on the GroupID column and Order by Date and Time column. After I got the previous value, the current record minus previous value AS RESULT. But something wrong, the result is bad. Some records get the previous value, and some records is not. I couldn't understand.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use a common table expression with ROW_NUMBER() to number each row in time order within a group. Getting the previous value is then as simple as left joining the cte with itself to get the row with the same groupid and a row number that is one less. Something like;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT groupid, odate, otime, ovalue,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY groupid ORDER BY odate, otime) rn
  FROM table1
)
SELECT a.groupid, a.odate, a.otime, a.ovalue, b.ovalue Prev_oValue,
       a.ovalue-b.ovalue oResult
FROM cte a
LEFT JOIN cte b
  ON a.groupid = b.groupid
 AND a.rn = b.rn + 1
ORDER BY a.groupid, a.odate, a.otime
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5376/7).

Comment: This one is more shorter then Navneet Verma answer, but u need to change the oResult calculation. It should be a.ovalue - b.ovalue

Comment: @Haminteu Ah yes, fixed, thanks. That's what I get for writing SQL before first morning coffee :)

Comment: @Haminteu As to which is "better", you should test it against your data volumes, or if they're small enough not to matter, use the one that's clearer for you to read for when you need to modify it :)

Comment: @Haminteu What error are you getting? [This simple view sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f6736/1) seems to work.

Comment: What I meant is View On SQL.

Comment: So Am I right? Your syntax couldn't saved as a view on SQL.

Comment: @Haminteu There is afaik no way to have ORDER BY in a view, but if you order when selecting from the view it shouldn't be a problem; http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0af38/1